# Nested rules with selectors in LESS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, nested

I have the following CSS-rule(s):

```
div > a,
div > span {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Is it somehow possible to nest `a` and `span` within the `div >`, e.g.

```
div > {
  a, span {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
div {
  > a,
  > span {
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference? Do I have to add an ampersand in front of the selector? (e.g. `& > a`)?

Comment: @Edward: The above code should work with or without ampersand (parent selector).

Comment: Sure, check http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules for more details. You'd use the ampersand when nesting pseudoselectors for instance. In other words, when there's no space between the parent and the child. You can also play with it on an online compiler: http://winless.org/online-less-compiler